# Parameter 'image_url' (value http:null) is not a valid URL format

Tags: php, e-commerce, pinterest

I am trying to share my products from my e-shop, but I am getting this error:

> Parameter 'image_url' (value http:null) is not a valid URL format.

I have read previous answers about this topic, but I still don't have the ability to solve it...
My template has this code in `node-product.tpl.php`, which is the template for node-products:

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=<?php print $base_url . "/" . drupal_get_path_alias('node/' . $node->nid); ?>&amp;description=<?php print $node->title; ?>" class="_3">
    <i class="fa fa-pinterest-square"></i>
</a>
```

I tried to add this code:

```
&media=<?php render($content['product:field_product_gallery']); ?>
```

but I still have a problem to share this on pinterest. I believe that something is wrong with the image rendering, but I am not a programmer, so I don't know how to solve this.
Any help would be appreciated!
Thank you in advance!

Comment: I would suggest using Pinterest's integration script. It will make it easier. [Documentation](https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/widgets/getting-started/)

Comment: thank you for your answer... Great! It works! Can i customize the pin it image like class="fa fa-pinterest-square" in order to be the same size like the others (fb, twitter)? Thank you again!

Comment: Definitely. Check out the [Widget Builder](https://developers.pinterest.com/tools/widget-builder/). You can use the `custom` tag to use your own stylings.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to `urlencode()` the **url**, **media** and **description**, which is not exist in your code.
So in your case the `href` becomes:

`http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=<?php print urlencode($base_url . "/" . drupal_get_path_alias('node/' . $node->nid)); ?>&amp;description=<?php print urlencode($node->title); ?>`